# EF Code First with only dependent to principal navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-6.0

I know Microsoft has [a detailed document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one) mentioning plenty of Entity Framework entity design scenarios for one-to-one relationships, but unfortunately I could not find a solution for my case over there.

Let's say I have the below listed two classes:

```cs
// Principal (parent)
class Blog
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

and

```cs
// Dependent (child)
public class BlogHeader
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public Blog Blog {get; set;} // reference navigation to principal
}
```

How can I explicitly define a one-to-one required relationship between them using the EF fluent API. I am trying with the below code:

```cs
internal class BlogHeaderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BlogHeader>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BlogHeader> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("BlogHeaders");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Blog).WithOne().HasForeignKey<BlogHeader>(x => x.Blog);
    }
}
```

but I see the below exception while adding a new migration:

> 'Blog' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'BlogHeader' because it is configured as a navigation.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It is _literally impossible_ to have true `1:1` relationships without deferrable-constraints, and most RDBMS do not support deferrable-constraints. (However your posted code seems to describe a `1-0..1` relationship, which is **not** a `1:1` relationship).

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I was trying to do with the below code:

```cs
builder.HasOne(x => x.Blog).WithOne().HasForeignKey<BlogHeader>("BlogId").IsRequired();
```

But there is one caveat, which is the explicit foreign key name, as a hardcoded string. If someone knows a way without specifying an explicit foreign key name, let me know.

Comment: What’s wrong with having to specify an FK name?

Answer (score 0):

The right classes are:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }            
    public BlogHeader BlogHeader { get; set; }
}
public class BlogHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need to specify API Fluent Configuration because EF "knows" which are the right keys, but if You like it, You can write:

```
internal class BlogHeaderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BlogHeader>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BlogHeader> builder)
   {
       builder.ToTable("BlogHeaders");
       builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
       builder.HasOne(x => x.Blog).WithOne(x => x.BlogHeader).HasForeignKey<BlogHeader>(x => x.BlogId);
                    
   }
```

}